# Get CouchDB documents that have a start before and an end after a specified time

Tags: nosql, couchdb

I have a large set of documents that, among other things, contain a *"startDate"* and *"endDate"*.

My problem is that I am trying to make a view that can take a date and return all documents that have a *startDate* before as well as an *endDate* after the specified time. If both timestamps are before or both after the specified time, I don't want them to be returned.

Comment: So far, I have only been able to make a view where I pass in two keys and get documents between them. I think the real issue here is that I don't have two keys, just one.

Comment: So, just to get you right, you want your view to return only documents that are between two dates?

Comment: that's right. I still haven't found a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like 2 lookups are needed, so you might as well make 2 views, (start_date_view, end_date_view), query both views with startKey= and endKey= that make sense, then filter the results.
To my knowledge, couchDB can not make a view that can be queried in the way you desire. the views in couchDB are fairly simple.